# Can a Windows 7 PC remotely manage Hyper-V on a Server 2012R2

Tags: hyper-v

I have a Windows 7 (W7 Pro, SP1, up to date) desktop, and a Windows Server 2012R2 server, running the Hyper-V role with a number of VMs.

I've gone through with [HVRemote](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Hyper-V-Remote-Management-26d127c6) and set everything up on both ends, HVRemote's diagnostic check claims I have no issues at either end, and yet the Hyper-V Manager consistenly fails to connect ("The operation on computer '{Computer Name}' failed.")

Can W7 remotely administer Server 2012R2? I've previously used the same desktop to manage a remote Hyper-V instance on server 2012 (not R2).

I don't know where else to look. I've dug through the event logs and not found anything promising, and I'm out of ideas for how to try and diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No You cannot manage 2012 R2 from Win7 RSAT. You need Win 8.1 to manage 2012 R2.

You can use Win7 to manage 2012(non R2) (but not all function will work/show). As example in Win7 RSAT there is no "Move" option to move virtual machine. In 8/2012 - it is available. Also some VM reconfiguration via RSAT from Win7 on 2012 will fail but the same done from win8 do not fail.

I recommend using powershell to manage Hyper-V 2012R2 if You do not have yet 8.1 now.

We had same problem in our IT dept and decided to always move to latest client OS in IT Dept to be able to always manage new editions of Window Server. Before we upgraded win7 to win8 we used powershell.

ps. If You already have Win 8.1 RSAT there is a bug and You need to apply this:
http://blog.mpecsinc.ca/2009/06/hyper-v-error-access-denied-unable-to.html

Comment: This is what I suspected, but I couldn't find it freaking documented anywhere (can you provide any links to MS documentation stating this?). Right now, I'm using RDP to interact with the remote console, as well as manage bringup of new VMs. I do not have any W8 platforms in-house at all (this is a home lab).

Comment: @FakeName If You check the download page for RSAT for Win7 and RSAT for Win8 You will see supported OS - Win7 RSAT http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7887 - " .... to manage roles and features that are installed on computers that are running Windows Server® 2008 R2, Windows Server® 2008, or Windows Server® 2003."

Comment: it's also documented in this MS article with the nice table of supported client OS / Hyper V OS: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn632582(v=ws.11).aspx